# Returning UTF-8 from a web service

Tags: xml, web-services

Previous: [Returning info from a Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479591/returning-info-from-a-web-service)

I thought the previous answer made 100% sense, and I though I was out of the woods, but it still fails.

An app I'm working with still seems to think what is being returned from the web service is ASCII encoded.  Debugging it shows:

```
<Envelope><Body><ReturnOneResponse><ReturnOneResult>&lt;xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"&gt;&lt;Entry&gt;&lt;Symbol&gt;PACR&lt;/Symbol&gt;&lt;Company&gt;Pacer International, Inc.&lt;/Company&gt;&lt;MarketCap&gt;$229.0M&lt;/MarketCap&gt;&lt;PE&gt;18.7&lt;/PE&gt;&lt;Price&gt;6.56&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Change&gt;0.42&lt;/Change&gt;&lt;PctChange&gt;6.84%&lt;/PctChange&gt;&lt;YTDChange&gt;107.59%&lt;/YTDChange&gt;&lt;/Entry&gt;</ReturnOneResult></ReturnOneResponse></Body></Envelope>
```

So everything being returned from the web service seems to be changed into ASCII, and seems to refuse to read as UTF-8.

Since my previous code in the above link, I also changed my string invocation:

```
string value = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>";
```

Still, that didn't help.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Indent code 4 spaces to prevent SO from eating XML. I fixed it for you.

Comment: "So everything being returned from the web service seems to be changed into ASCII." How are you coming to this conclusion? I don't see any evidence of mis-encoded text, only double-escaped XML, which is a different problem.

Comment: OK, "double-escaped XML"...  I go looking for that online.

Comment: http://www.asp101.com/articles/colin/webservices/default.asp - One thing I've never done is to place the DLL in /bin.  Is this still something that needs to be done with IIS7/IIS7.5?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that somewhere your string is being escaped.
maybe if you use something like Server.HTMLDecode to unescape your string it will work

Comment: I'm reading in XML from a text-based file.  Is there any way there's a problem with the text file itself?  I'm not sure how to apply your suggestion to my case, but will keep searching.

Comment: A escaped string is a string that you convert all special symbols to there character code equivalent so you can discern strings from the actual language (XML,SQL,etc). The point is, when your webservice returns the XML, it's escaping the whole code. That's good when you want to show the string(e.g.:on a browser), but when saving the XML to a file, you need to have unescaped XML. You have to instruct the part from your service that saves the text file to unescape the contents before writing it to the file.

Comment: The XML file that is being loaded, contains "valid XML" and can be read from PowerShell without problems, so it isn't a syntax error from the XML input, I'm thinking...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language/system you're using in the web service.  However, just setting the XML header to include an encoding does not cause the data stream to be encoded that way.  You have to take some action to specify the output encoding at the point where you write to the output stream.

EDIT: The double-escaping is probably normal for a SOAP reply containing XML.  Otherwise the SOAP protocol could be easily broken by a misbehaving SOAP service.  The SOAP envelope/body MUST be valid XML, so any embedded XML data must be encoded to prevent an error from making the SOAP envelope/body invalid.

You will have to unescape it in the client.

Comment: Sorry, the posting links to my previous question/attempt, which is in C#.

Comment: Do you set the output encoding to UTF-8 for the C# stream? Also see Laurence Gonsalves' comment -- are you sure the output is not UTF-8?  If there are no characters with codepoints > 127 in the output, you won't be able to tell if it's UTF-8 or not, as ASCII and UTF-8 are identical for characters 0x00 thru 0x7F.

Comment: My ASCII comment is based on something the vendor support told me.  I'm sorry if I'm passing on bad information.